# How to uniquely recognize a client from a server in web app?

Tags: java, javascript, grails, web-applications

I am building a web application that need to recognize its clients uniquely(not cookies), so that client can get access to his/her preferences he/she has set during his previous http session.

I am building my using java, hibernate, spring, struts

Comment: What's wrong with cookies? This is their exact purpose. If you are only targeting modern browsers you could use the web storage API, but cookies are probably your best bet, along with storing a unique session ID on the server side with the data you need to remember.

Comment: Cookies (good) or a unique id in each URL (bad). If you need anything else, you need to really elaborate *why* neither of these cut it for you.

Comment: @Cecchi What if cookies are disabled? Then my web app will become helpless...

Comment: If cookie are disabled then you fall back on a default set of preferences. Users should know if they disable cookies they are likely to lose some website functionality.

Comment: Also most Websites reley on the use of cookies nowerdays...

Comment: If cookies are disabled, it's made exacly for situation when user don't want to be tracked by your site.

Comment: If cookies are disabled you can use URL-Rewriting with your servlet container... but it is too way dangerous from security perspective.

Comment: There are various fingerprinting techniques by they are in the ethical grey area.  Do you need to be able track the user just during a session or across sessions?